# Demonstrate by the Lyapunov method

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

Demonstrate by the Lyapunov method or any other method that a system described by the equation $ \ddot{y} + h (\dot{y}) + f (y) = 0 $ is globally asymptotically stable if the functions $ f, h $ satisfy $ yf (y) \geq \xi y^{2}$ for some $ \xi> 0 $ and $ \dot{y}h(\dot{y})> 0 $, $\forall\dot{y} \neq0 $

Comment: Do you have any more assumptions on $f$ and $h$? For example, do you have that $h(0)=f(0)=0$?

Comment: Exact! I also had that doubt ... but the exercise only poses inequalities as restrictions.

Comment: $yf(y)>0$ for $y\ne0$ means that $y$ and $f(y)$ are of the same sign. As $f$ is (tacitly) assumed to be (at least) continuous, $f(0)=0$. Similarly for $h$.

Answer (score 1):

One obvious Lyapunov function is $$V=\frac12\dot y^2+F(y),$$ with $F$ an anti-derivative of $f$. Then $$\dot V=-h(\dot y)\dot y<0,$$ so that the level of $V$ continuously decreases along solutions. Now you only need to explore the shape of the level sets of the minima of $V$.

---

Setting $F(0)=0$ we get $$F(y)=\int_0^1f(sy)y\,ds\ge\int_0^1 s\,ds\,ξy^2=\frac12ξy^2$$ which not only shows positivity for $y\ne 0$ but coercivity. The minimum of $V$ is then $0$ at $(y,\dot y)=(0,0)$ and all trajectories converge towards that point.

Comment: What assures us that $F(y) \ge 0$ ?

Comment: @Cesareo As I wrote in my previous comment, $f$ is positive on $(0,\infty)$ and negative on $(-\infty,0)$. So it suffices to take the antiderivative $F$ such that $F(0)=0$.